# Bluetooth LE from Cordova app to Linux device

Tags: linux, cordova, bluetooth

I need some guidance. In a nutshell, I need to be able to configure and control a device with the smart phone app over BLE.

For example, change IP address of my Raspberry Pi. To make that happen, I need 2 things.

1. Simple Android/iOS app that takes IP address parameters as an input, and then communicates over Bluetooth to the RPi. Note that the device needs to be discovered and connected from within the app (without going to "Settings" and pairing).
2. Build some server process on the Raspberry Pi that listens to USB Bluetooth dongle, receives the command with parameters and acts accordingly.

So I need help building the BLE portion of this project.

I have several years of smartphone app development experience, and 10+ years of Linux system programming. In other words, building a simple Cordova app, as well as Linux process that changes IP address is really not an issue.

However, I am totally new to Bluetooth. Can you point me to the right direction? I am sure this problem has already been solved few thousand times. Is there a tutorial? Or maybe a skeleton code I use as a starting point? Also, any recommendation for BLE USB dongle?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: From the SO help pages: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be harder to find a better guide to implement low energy technology on the RaspberryPi than this one :

https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi.pdf

After this , you can download a random app on the Playstore/Appstore and check that your RaspberryPi is actually acting as a BLE device.

Finally you can start creating your own app using several available BLE plugins like :

https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central